# How can I change a ViewModel Property and save it to all my pages?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the default `MasterDetailPage` project, where I have an `ItemPage` and an `ItemDetailPage` (when I click in one item). In my `ItemDetailPage` I changed the `Item.Text` property to `batata` and I was expecting the `ItemPage Item` text to change, but it didn't. How can I change the property in my `ItemDetailPage` and change it in the `ItemPage` too?

#### ItemPage Xaml code

```xml
<StackLayout>
  <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
            ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                   FontSize="16" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                   LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                   Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                   FontSize="13" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

```cs
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemsViewModel viewModel;

    ItemDetailViewModel itemViewModel;

    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    }

    async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.BindingContext = null;

        var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if(itemViewModel == null)
            itemViewModel = new ItemDetailViewModel(item);

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(itemViewModel));

        // Manually deselect item.
        ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;

        this.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
            viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

```xml
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
  <Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
  <Label Text="{Binding Item.Text}" FontSize="Small"/>
  <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
  <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
</StackLayout>
```

```cs
public partial class ItemDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemDetailViewModel viewModel;

    public ItemDetailPage(ItemDetailViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        viewModel.Item.Text = "batata";

        BindingContext = this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }
}
```

ItemsViewModel

```
 public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }

        public ItemsViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Browse";
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
            {
                var newItem = item as Item;
                Items.Add(newItem);
                await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
            });
        }

        async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;

            IsBusy = true;

            try
            {
                Items.Clear();
                var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

ItemsDetailViewModel

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public ItemDetailViewModel(Item item = null)
        {
            Title = item?.Text;
            Item = item;
        }
    }
```

ItemModel:

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the classes `Item` and `ItemDetailViewModel`?

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas I just added in my question.

Comment: The class `Item` is still missing, though – and it is the most important one, since you are binding against some of its properties.

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to properties of the class `Item` that don't notify about their changes, such as `Text` and `Description`. Because of it, the value in the view doesn't update when the value of the property has been changed.

You can solve it by [implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) in `Item`:

```cs
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Id { get; set; }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            if (_text != value)
            {
                _text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            if (_description != value)
            {
                _description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would also recommend you don't bind to nested properties, since that can be problematic. Thus, instead of binding to `Item.Text` and `Item.Description`, just bind directly to properties in your viewmodel.

For example, in `ItemDetailViewModel` you could create two properties called `ItemText` and `ItemDescription`:

```cs
public string ItemText => Item?.Text;
public string ItemDescription => Item?.Description;
```

```xml
<!-- Updated bindings -->
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
  <Label Text="Text:" FontSize="Medium" />
  <Label Text="{Binding ItemText}" FontSize="Small"/>
  <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Medium" />
  <Label Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" FontSize="Small"/>
</StackLayout>
```

To make sure these properties notify about their changes whenever the corresponding properties of the `Item` change, you will need to subscribe to the event `Item.PropertyChanged` so you can propagate the updates:

```cs
// (Assuming the base viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged the same way than Item)
public class ItemDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Item _item;
    public Item Item
    {
        get => _item;
        set
        {
            if (_item != value)
            {
                if (_item != null)
                {
                    // Unsubscribe from the old item
                    _item.PropertyChanged -= OnItemPropertyChanged;
                }

                _item = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();

                if (value != null)
                {
                    // Subscribe to the new item
                    value.PropertyChanged += OnItemPropertyChanged;
                }

                // Since the entire item has changed, we notify 
                // about changes in all the dependant properties
                Title = Item?.Text;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemText));
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemDescription));
            }
        }
    }

    public string ItemText => Item?.Text;
    public string ItemDescription => Item?.Description;

    public ItemDetailViewModel(Item item = null)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    private void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // When a property of the item changes, we propagate the changes
        // to the properties of this viewmodel that now depend on it
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Item.Text))
        {
            Title = Item?.Text;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemText));
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Item.Description))
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemDescription));
        }
    }
}
```

This code is a little bit messy and could be improved to make it more elegant, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Ok he changed the first item that I clicked, but the second, and the others, didnt.

Comment: I don't know if it will help or not, but please see my edit.

Comment: I did some changes, because some errors were ocurring.

Comment: Yes, your edit is correct. I wrote the code without running it or anything and forgot about that detail. Good catch!

Comment: Unfortunately is not working. Is doing same thing, not updating the others one.

Comment: The problem is that you are keeping a reference to `ItemDetailViewModel` in the field `itemViewModel` of `ItemsPage`, so you are always setting "batata" in the same item.

Comment: And you think that is the cause of not updating the others? If it is I can just change.

Comment: Yeah I think you right, cause I only change 1 time for all, and he just changed in first Item clicked.

Comment: Yeah, if you remove the field `itemViewModel` and use a local variable instead, it should work fine – ideally, though, you should be saving the instances of `ItemDetailViewModel` somewhere to avoid creating new ones all the time.

Comment: But how can I change the text from the specific label withoud object sender in constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193046/discussion-between-julio-e-rodriguez-cabanas-and-lol-jovem).

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to bind to a static property

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Add a reference in xaml to your location of the MyClass file and bind to the static property

```
{x:Static local:MyClass.MyProperty}">
```

Comment: But why Static?

Comment: It's just a way to go. I never used a MasterDetailPage